# Recreating sklearn linear regression from coefficients and intercept

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am attempting to write my own linear regression function using the coefficients and intercept achieved using the `sklearn LinearRegression` model. I have 11 features. I am using `model.coef_[0]` to extract the coefficient for feature 1 etc.. When I recreate the regression function the results are vastly different.

Does `model.coef_[0]` always correspond to the coefficient for feature 1 etc or do I need to do something to check this? Any tips on this would be greatly appreciated

**Update**

This was my mistake. I copy and pasted the values directly from `print(coef_)` and this resulted in a rounding error!